# Incompatible Software with 10.9.1

Tags: macos

I just updated to 10.9.1 and when the system restarted I got a window that said "Incompatible Software". But I got a Little Snitch window on top of it obscuring that window. For whatever reason I could not close the LittleSnitch window nor could I switch to the "Incompatible Software" window. I tried multiple times and the only way out was to restart the machine. All was well after that.

But I don't know what software was listed in the window and what options I had. Is there anyway to have that window back?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the answer to what you asked but Incompatible software programs will be moved to `/Incompatible Software`. So just look and see what is in that directory